# Any tag driven multi-media manager?

Tags: video, images

First off, I have many multimedia files and before I mindlesly write this tool myself I want to know if something like this does not exist already.

Main features:

1. Need to attach different tags to these files
2. Need to attach tags **recursively** to all files in folder
3. Files added sometimes, sometimes removed, need some syncronization button, or some periodic task which can find out changes (diff) on file hierarchy.
4. One file for this index (SQLite or something), so I can pretty simply move entire folder with this file index and everything works as worked before move.
5. Search queries by tags and names
6. Preview for multi-media including flash (*.flv).

Comment: What OS should it run on, and what is your prize limit if it comes to paid solutions?

Comment: "*Multimedia*" is a pretty broad term. What kinds of files are you planning on tagging? Video files? Photos and Pictures? Music and Audio? All of the above? Would something like [TagSpaces](https://www.tagspaces.org) satisfy your needs?

Comment: By multimedia I mean every commonly used multimedia file: picture, video, gif, etc. As to OS it is Windows, paid solutions is not an option. If there is only paid solution, then more reason to write it myself and browse as open-source project.